# FB Like button is transferring wrong UR

Tags: url, iframe, facebook-graph-api

I have an iFrame on my website that pops up and will play a video.  The iframe source location is:

http://www.fivepointsusa.com/video.php?id=1&v=3_2.flv

The like button WILL pick this link up properly.  However its a pretty bland page as it's designed to be inside a specified sized iframe.

The link that i WANT to show is:

http://www.fivepointsusa.com/bio.php?id=1#!prettyPhoto/0/

That link will bring the user to my bio page, open the iFrame and start the video.  When I get my script to insert the correct address into the

However when i click the Like button, it drops off the #!prettyPhoto/0/ part.  This is the most important part of the link...

How can i get the rest of the URL to show?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Web browsers are not supposed to transfer the fragment (the part after the '#') when requesting a resource from a server, so that part gets dropped. You can get around this by putting the '!prettyPhoto/0/' part in a URL parameter, e.g. '?id=1&path=prettyPhoto/0/' (make sure to URL encode the parameters).